# Html parsing with Agility

Tags: c#, html, parsing

Could someone please help with resolving the trouble parsing sequential tags of Html by Agility in C#? I have 2 question as listed below.

in this case, I want to parse following Html and store them into a structure (list, stack, etc) so I can use these data effectively.

```
<h3> header </h3>
<p> paragraph 1</p>
<p>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="www.gizmodo.com">Gizmodo</a>
</p>
<ul> 
<li> something is here with a download
<a href="www.google.com">link</a>
</li>
<li> hello 
<img src="www.imagesource.com"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

1. How to parse these data in sequential manner?

   If I use `var ParaTags = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("p");`, 
   then I can only get all "p" tags. but I don't know how to get "h3" then "p" in sequence, because "p" is not inside "h3".

following code will returns me all hyperlinks,

```
var links =
    from paras in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("p")
    from hyperLinks in paras.Descendants("a").Where(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value != "")
    select hyperLinks;
```

1. What's the best way to parse and store those mixed content with string, hyperlinks, and images?
   so I can output them later in a efficient way? List, stack?
   Another word, I want to store every possible content from html and reserve its format if possible. so I can resemble the content in proper format once i reload it onto the app.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what information you want to extract from this HTML and store. Do you want to extract all `href` attributes of hyperlinks? Or `href` and `src` of images?

Comment: I want every possible content from that html, which includes h3, all p, li, href, and img src. and if possible, the format too. Thanks.

Comment: If memory serves, you can use the  XmlReader on the HtmlDocument class, which would give you the sequential read through of each tag in order, but I'm not sure that the output you expect would provide you with something that you would be able to reconstruct into the exact Html.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract all `href` and `src` attributes you may try this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.Load("test.html");
        var links =
            from element in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
            let href = element.Attributes["href"]
            let src = element.Attributes["src"]
            where href != null || src != null
            select href != null ? href.Value : src.Value;

        foreach (var link in links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(link);
        }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
www.google.com
www.gizmodo.com
www.google.com
www.imagesource.com
```

Comment: but I also need to extract text of h3 and p too!